# regex to match word but not with < or > next to it c#

Tags: c#, regex

From this string  "asdfasdf obama blahobama obama. >obama"

it should not match blahobama or >obama

at the moment I have this regex \bobama\b

but it also finds ">obama"

I only want to find the first two "obama"s.

not the third. >obama should not find a match.

Comment: can you explain better please? do you want a generic way to find only the first two instances of multiple times present word or what else?

Comment: I want to match the word obama every time it appears except when it has > or < on either side. so this matchs obama. but this obama< doesnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[^>]\bobama\b
```

But it will not pick `obama` that starts a line, if you want to pick it:

```
((^)|([^>]\b))obama\b
```

Comment: but this ((^)|([^>]\b))obama\b adds a leading space on the first match  of this  "asdfasdf obama blahobama obama. >obama". I am using this in a rgx.replace so I cant have any leading or trailing spaces on the match.

Comment: this [^>]\bobama\b finds ">obama" but adds a leading space to the " obama"

Comment: @Harry McCarney Use groups then: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx

Comment: please could you give me a little example. This leading space is a real pain. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A simple option is to use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) around the word to specifically disallow `<` and `>`:

```
(?<![<>])\bobama\b(?![<>])
```

[Working example on Regex Storm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28?%3C!%5B%3C%3E%5D%29%5Cbobama%5Cb%28?!%5B%3C%3E%5D%29&i=asdfasdf%20obama%20blahobama%20obama.%20%3Eobama)

Similarly, you can use [Unicode categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories) as you see fit:

```
(?<!\p{S})\bobama\b(?!\p{S})
```

You can combine them using character classes, for example, to also exclude numbers, instead of `\p{S}` use `[\p{S}\p{N}]`.

[Working example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28?%3C!%5Cp%7BS%7D%29%5Cbobama%5Cb%28?!%5Cp%7BS%7D%29&i=asdfasdf%20obama%20blahobama%20obama.%20%3Eobama%20obama!%20obama%3C)